# How do I add a panel to a specific column of a dashboard?

Tags: javascript, extjs, dashboard, extjs-mvc, extjs5

I have an Ext.dashboard.Dashboard component. I am trying to add a panel to a specific column of the dashboard. dashboard.addView(view) works great for adding a panel to the dashboard, but it only adds it to the bottom of first column. I want to be able to add a panel to columnIndex 1.

The addView method has a second argument for the columnIndex, but whenever a columnIndex is specified, an exception is thrown due to a bug in ExtJS. I filed a bug report here http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?298857-Exception-is-thrown-when-adding-a-dashboard-panel-to-a-specific-columnIndex&p=1091252#post1091252

Does anyone know of a work around for this or has anyone else been able to add a panel to a column of a dashboard a different way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the test case you posted in the forums you specify a `columnIndex` of 1.  If you do a little debugging you'll see that the item that that references is actually a `columnsplitter`, not a `dashboard-column`.  A `columnsplitter`, which obviously is between each pair of columns, does not have an add function, which is why you're getting the `undefined is not a function` error. So the index of the second column is actually 2, and if you specify that as `columnIndex` it will work as expected.

Comment: Thanks. This fixed it. That should really be mentioned in the documentation though.